# Is there a way to keep track of the elements and to loop the menu?

Tags: java, loops, queue

The program needs to be able to enter people into a Queue and keep track of them. the user has 3 options "A" to enter a new person(int) into the queue, "N" to just let the queue be processed, and "Q" to quit the queue and to then display how many people are in the queue. I can't quite figure out how to loop and keep track.

```
package pkg3650queue;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Scanner;  // Import the Scanner class

public class Main {
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
         Queue<Integer> line = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner addperson = new Scanner(System.in);

    String option;
do {
    System.out.println("Type A to add a person to the line (# of requests)\n"
            + "Type N to do nothing and allow the line to be processed\n"
            + "Type Q to quit the application\n");
    option = input.nextLine();

    if(option.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
            System.out.println("Enter a number to add a person to the line: ");
            int addtoLine = addperson.nextInt();
            line.add(addtoLine);
            System.out.println(line);
            System.out.println("There are " + line.size() + " people in the queue");
        }  else if (option.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
        if(line.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("There are no elements in the line to be processed");
            System.exit(0);  
        }
        else{
            int requestsProccessed = line.remove();
            System.out.println(requestsProccessed);
            System.out.println(line);
            System.out.println("There are " + line.size() + " people in the queue");
            }
        }

    } while (!option.equalsIgnoreCase("Q"));

System.out.println("Q was chosen. The number of ppl in this queue are " + line.size());
}
}
```

Comment: Not related to your problem, but to simplify your code, instead of using `option.equals("q") || option.equals("Q")` you can do `option.equalsIgnoreCase("q")`.  See the [corresponding doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String))

Comment: You may just put all your code (from the displying of the question, to the end) inside a loop. Use a boolean flag as the condition of your loop. When the user enter `q` set the flag to false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean how to loop the user input? You can use a `do-while`:

```
    String option;
    do {
        System.out.println("Type A to add a person to the line (# of requests)\n"
                + "Type N to do nothing and allow the line to be processed\n"
                + "Type Q to quit the application\n");
        option = input.nextLine();

        if(option.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
            // do something
        } else if (option.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
            // do something
        }

        // notice we don't need an if for 'Q' here. This loop only determines how many
        // times we want to keep going. If it's 'Q', it'll exit the while loop, where
        // we then print the size of the list.

        } while (!option.equalsIgnoreCase("Q"));

    System.out.println("Q was chosen. The number of ppl in this queue are " + line.size());
```

Note I didn't test this code, but it should get you going on the right track.

Also notice that we do not need a `System.exit(0)` in this case, as the program will just naturally end. Though there are exceptions, you normally do not want to use `System.exit(0)`, and would rather find ways for code to 'finish itself'.

Comment: Thank you it works. But I noticed another problem while trying to run it, whenever i try to use "n" and let the queue process itself it only subtracts 1 from the first int ie [5,3,2,1] -> n -> 4(only displays the first int in queue) and if I add another int (6) its going to display [5,3,2,1,6] . any advise?

Comment: @Osama I'm not sure what you mean. What would you like it to do when the user selects n?

Comment: Ok, so let's think like programmers! You have a LinkedList and you'd like to remove the first int in the queue. So if we go here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html
and check which method allows us to do that (hint, it's `pop()`).

So you would do: 
`int requestsProccessed = line.pop();`

Comment: Also, I would appreciate if you accepted my answer if you thought it was helpful :)

Comment: Sorry, `pop()` will remove the last element that was put in. Since you're dealing with a Queue, you will want to use the `removeFirst()` method.

Comment: what are you removing first from? `line` right? So
`requestsProcessed = line.removeFirst();`